# Ошибка при реализации чистого виртуального метода

Tags: c++

Не понимаю почему ошибка и как ее решить.(ошибка на вызове attributes в конструкторе)
[image: 1]

```
    class shader
    {
    public:
```

shader()
    {
        attributes();
    }

    virtual void attributes() = 0;
};

class staticShader : public shader
{
public:
    staticShader() : shader()
    {

    };

    void attributes() override
    {
        std::cout << "attribute";
    }
};


int main()
{
    staticShader shader{};

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что когда вы вызываете виртуальную функцию attributes() из конструктора класса shader, объект класса staticShader еще не создан, соответственно нет метода, который необходимо вызвать.

Замените:

```
virtual void attributes() = 0;
```

на

```
virtual void attributes()
{
     std::cout << "base::attribute";
}
```

И вы увидите, что хоть вы и создаете объекта класса staticShader, его виртуальная функция не будет вызвана.

Comment: я не понимаю сути если я создам абсолютную виртуальную функцию которая не может вызваться в конструкторе зачем тогда она нужна. ммм да...

Comment: Никто не мешает вызвать функцию в конструкторе того класса, в котором она определена. В данном случае это staticShader.

Comment: @АРТЕМ Фролов, в чем проблема создать объект и затем сразу же вызвать виртуальную функцию, в чем необходимость вызова именно из конструктора?

Comment: @Александр я понял 1 что с++ конструкторы лучше заменять на методы инициализации. спасибо за объяснение причины.

Comment: @АРТЕМФролов, тогда заменяйте сразу и деструкторы. В них виртуальные функци тоже нельзя вызывать